# Find the differential equation of this function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the differential equation of $$y = A\cos{(\log{x})} + B\sin{(\log{x})}$$

There are two arbitrary constants, so I think I have to differentiate $y$ twice. But I'm getting a very ugly equation upon differentiating, and I don't think I can't eliminate the arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$ using those.

Comment: Hint: find a relationship between the terms $x^2y''$, $xy'$ and $y$. This kind of differential equation is famous and named after Euler.

Comment: It might help, after you've found the first derivative $y'=\frac{1}{x}\left[-A\sin(\log x)+B\cos(\log x)\right]$ to multiply both sides of the equation by $x$ to ease the differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{lrl}&(y)'&=&\frac1x\left[-A\sin{(\ln{x})}+B\cos{(\ln{x})}\right]\\[0.2cm]\implies& xy'&=&-A\sin{(\ln{x})}+B\cos{(\ln{x})}\\[0.2cm]\implies& (xy')'&=&\frac1x\left[-A\cos{(\ln{x})}-B\sin{(\ln{x})}\right]=\frac1x(-y)\\[0.2cm]\implies& y+xy'+x^2y''&=&0\end{array} which is called the [Cauchy-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)  or most commonly just Euler's differential equation.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know what Cauchy-Euler was!